# Apple Appstore Screenshot Submission issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

[image]I am having trouble submitting screenshots to the app store even with the right metadata.   I tried generating screenshots myself as well as using a third-party service.  I even created a new app to submit the screenshots with.   Is anyone else having the issue?  I went through the questions on this site where people had similar issues in the past and tried all of them.

[image: Appstore Screenshot Submission Issue]

Comment: Hello @Joti, This issue is occurring due screen shot size.

Comment: Can you please tell me the screenshot size of 5.5" display?

Comment: 1242x2208 72px/inch

Comment: @RajJoshi  - But screenshots are of the size that are required by app store. This is happening for all screen sizes.    Even the screenshots taken from iPhonex are not being accepted.

Comment: 1. Was the iPhone screenshot, that led to your error image above, made on an iPhone Plus with 5.5" screen? 2. Did you not crop the image (e.g. remove the iOS status bar)?

Comment: You should take screen shots from iPhone 8 plus or 5.5" display and resize them in 1242x2208, I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @meaning-matters - screenshots were taken from the simulator

Comment: @RajJoshi even iPhone X that I took using the phone is it accepted. Apple has been a very frustrating experience

Comment: @RajJoshi  I meant not accepted

Comment: I m still having trouble submitting the screenshots.  Please see the attached screenshot that I generated by using the command S key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - strangely enough I can upload images using Safari browser and a hotspot from my phone.  Looks like Chrome and iTunes Connect are not friends anymore.